# cuda linking error in Visual Studio when statically linking to device code

Tags: c++, cuda

Using Windows 64, Visual Studio 2022, Cuda 12, I cannot build and use static libraries using cuda device code. Example code:

```
-----------------
File Func.cuh:
-----------------
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

__device__ void func(double d);

void hostFunc(double d);

----------------
File Func.cu:
----------------
#include "Func.cuh"
#include <iostream>

__device__ void func(double d) {
    printf("device %f\n", sqrt(d));
}

void hostFunc(double d) {
    std::printf("host %f\n", std::sqrt(d));
}

-----------------
File Func2.cu:
-----------------
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "Func.cuh"

__global__ void test2(double d) {
    func(d);
}

int main() {
    hostFunc(2.0);

    test2<<<1, 1>>>(2.0);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

I want to build a static library out of Func, then use that library to link to and build Func2 into an executable. Directly on the windows command prompt this works very simply through

```
D:\temp>nvcc Func.cu -lib -o Func.lib -rdc true
Func.cu
tmpxft_000025c8_00000000-10_Func.cudafe1.cpp

D:\temp>nvcc Func2.cu -c -o Func2.obj -rdc true
Func2.cu
tmpxft_000043b8_00000000-10_Func2.cudafe1.cpp

D:\temp>nvcc Func2.obj Func.lib -o Func2.exe
Func2.obj
Func.lib
   library "Func2.lib" and object "Func2.exp" are built.
PS D:\temp> .\Func2
host 1.414214
device 1.414214
PS D:\temp>
```

But then, throuble is how to set up Projects in Visual Studio to do the very same thing? There I have a project `LibraryTest` which I then want to link to another project `LibraryTest2`, but based off default cuda projects, I tried different settings but I only get as far as this build process

```
Rebuild started...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: LibraryTest, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Compiling CUDA source file Func.cu...
1>
1>F:\reposVisualStudio\CudaTest\LibraryTest>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.0\bin\nvcc.exe"  --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu -rdc=true  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug  -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g  -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -Xcompiler "/FdF:\reposVisualStudio\CudaTest\x64\Debug\LibraryTest.pdb" -o F:\reposVisualStudio\CudaTest\LibraryTest\x64\Debug\Func.cu.obj "F:\reposVisualStudio\CudaTest\LibraryTest\Func.cu"
1>Func.cu
1>tmpxft_00002d18_00000000-7_Func.cudafe1.cpp
1>
1>F:\reposVisualStudio\CudaTest\LibraryTest>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -dlink  -o x64\Debug\LibraryTest.device-link.obj -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -Xcompiler "/FdF:\reposVisualStudio\CudaTest\x64\Debug\LibraryTest.pdb" -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.0\bin/crt" -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.0\lib\x64" cudart_static.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib cudart.lib cudadevrt.lib   -G  F:\reposVisualStudio\CudaTest\LibraryTest\x64\Debug\Func.cu.obj
1>cudart_static.lib
1>kernel32.lib
1>user32.lib
1>gdi32.lib
1>winspool.lib
1>comdlg32.lib
1>advapi32.lib
1>shell32.lib
1>ole32.lib
1>oleaut32.lib
1>uuid.lib
1>odbc32.lib
1>odbccp32.lib
1>cudart.lib
1>cudadevrt.lib
1>Func.cu.obj
1>LibraryTest.vcxproj -> F:\reposVisualStudio\CudaTest\x64\Debug\LibraryTest.lib
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: LibraryTest2, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>Compiling CUDA source file Func2.cu...
2>
2>F:\reposVisualStudio\CudaTest\LibraryTest2>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.0\bin\nvcc.exe"  --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu -rdc=true  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug  -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g  -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -Xcompiler "/Fdx64\Debug\vc143.pdb" -o F:\reposVisualStudio\CudaTest\LibraryTest2\x64\Debug\Func2.cu.obj "F:\reposVisualStudio\CudaTest\LibraryTest2\Func2.cu"
2>Func2.cu
2>tmpxft_00000c10_00000000-7_Func2.cudafe1.cpp
2>
2>F:\reposVisualStudio\CudaTest\LibraryTest2>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -dlink  -o x64\Debug\LibraryTest2.device-link.obj -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -Xcompiler "/Fdx64\Debug\vc143.pdb" -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.0\bin/crt" -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.0\lib\x64" -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.0\lib\x64" -LF:\reposVisualStudio\CudaTest\x64\Debug LibraryTest.lib cudart_static.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib cudart.lib cudadevrt.lib   -G  F:\reposVisualStudio\CudaTest\LibraryTest2\x64\Debug\Func2.cu.obj
2>CUDALINK : nvlink error : Undefined reference to '_Z4funcd' in 'F:/reposVisualStudio/CudaTest/LibraryTest2/x64/Debug/Func2.cu.obj'
```

I triple checked to have set `-rdc=true`, but I have no clue what else to change to get this built in VS??

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called "separable compilation" as explained in this
[NVIDA Blog post](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/separate-compilation-linking-cuda-device-code/)

Personally, I use [CMake](https://cmake.org) to generate a VisualStudio solution/project. CUDA was introduced as a language in 3.8 and supports got better in 3.17/3.18

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(so_cuda LANGUAGES CUDA CXX C)

set(CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 86)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

add_library(func Func.cu Func.cuh)
add_executable(example Func2.cu)
target_link_libraries(example func)
```

So you need to create a `build` directory and run `cmake` in it.

```bash
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
```

This will create a `so_cuda.sln` that you could open with VisualStudio.

If you do not want to use CMake, another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59383269/9038410) will give you the changes to make to your VisualStudio project

Comment: In your example you build the executable directly from all three files. But can you do the exact steps in cmake, that is:
 - first build a static library from Func.cu und and Func.cuh
 - in a second step compile Func2.cu and link to the library from step 1
. Because your example does not seem to involve a static library as far as I understand your cmake steps. Besides that, I have honored the settings described in that SO answer, I have -rdc=true, I have included cudadevrt.lib

Comment: I added the `add_library` step and concerning `cudadevrt.lib`, [CMake takes care of adding it for you](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/2062).

Comment: Well I got cmake and used your cmake code above to generate ```so_cuda.sln```. I then open that solution and build ```example.exe``` through Visual Studio 2022. This builds without any errors, but when I run the executable the only output I get is ```host 1.414214``` So the cuda code somehow is left from the build process (?) The executable should also print ```device 1.414214```